# Serialize Deserialize to/from xlsx

Tags: .net, serialization, xlsx

Given the following assemblage of classes (contrived):

```
public class School {
  [PrimaryKey]
  public string Name {get; set;}
  [Set]
  public IList<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}

public class Teacher {
  [PrimaryKey]
  public string Name {get; set;}
```

I'd like to have the object hierarchy serialized into a single sheet of an xlsx file, like

```
School.Name            Teacher.Name
Waldorf College        Ms. Briggs
Waldorf College        Mr. Smith
Starfleet Academy      Mr. Spock
Starfleet Academy      Mr. Sulu
Starfleet Academy      Mr. Kirk
```

I'd then like to deserialize any (sensible) modifications to the xlsx file, creating a new copy of School, and its associated Teachers.

Does anyone know of something similar to this that doesn't require touching the OpenXML libraries too much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use ADO.Net and LINQ.

[Using ADO.Net to Create and Alter an Excel File...](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=8&ArtID=2140435) <= first link I found hopefully it helps.

Comment: Sorry, these objects are going to be persisted to the database, and I don't want to mess with interop; I'll go the CSV route first.

Comment: If you are worried about using interop to create a new file then just create an excel file as a template and either have it beside the exe or as a resource.  Then you can just write to it with ADO.Net